# JavaScript <br /> doesn't work

Tags: javascript, break, line-breaks

I'm trying to insert a line breaker into javascript file to automatically add into html tag. I searched on google, but couldn't get any info on how to do it properly.

Screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLLv2.png)

```js
(function() {
 
 //Array of cars
 var car = ['Dodge', 'Nissan', 'Honda', 'Ford', 'Ferrari', 'Lamborghini', 'Audi', 'Porsche', 'Maserati', 'Bentley'];
 //Length of array
 var arrayLength = car.length;
 //Message
 var msg = '';

 //Loop through the items in the array
 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  //Current car to the message
  msg += "The car is: " + car[i] + "<br />";
 }

 //Upading HTML
 var el = document.getElementById("car");
 el.textContent = msg;
 
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <header>
  <h1>Page 5</h1>
 </header>
 <h2 id="car">Getting stuff from javascript with id="car"</h2>
 <footer>
 </footer>
 <script src="05.js"></script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` if you want the string to be parsed as HTML.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use innerHTML to be able to insert `<br/>` wish is an html  tag

```js
(function() {
 
 //Array of cars
 var car = ['Dodge', 'Nissan', 'Honda', 'Ford', 'Ferrari', 'Lamborghini', 'Audi', 'Porsche', 'Maserati', 'Bentley'];
 //Length of array
 var arrayLength = car.length;
 //Message
 var msg = '';

 //Loop through the items in the array
 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  //Current car to the message
  msg += "The car is: " + car[i] + "<br />";
 }

 //Upading HTML
 var el = document.getElementById("car");
 el.innerHTML = msg;
 
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <header>
  <h1>Page 5</h1>
 </header>
 <h2 id="car">Getting stuff from javascript with id="car"</h2>
 <footer>
 </footer>
 <script src="05.js"></script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```